# Perl regex help: character set, literal backslash, quote character

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file and I want to determine which lines contain a backslash followed by either a small letter "n" or a double-quote character. The following does NOT work for me. Would someone please explain why? Thank you!

```
my $pattern='\\[n"]';
if ($text =~ /$pattern/) {
    # Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within single quotes, there is no need to escape any character except embedded single quotes or a backslash at the end of the string. However a *pair* of backslashes is taken to be the first one escaping the second, so

```
my $pattern='\\[n"]'
```

is the same as

```
my $pattern='\[n"]'
```

and I hope you can now see that, if you compile that as a regex with `/$pattern/` the backslash will now be escaping the left square bracket `[`.

What you want within the regex is `/\\[n"]/` so you need *two* backslashes in the `$pattern` string.

Because one of every pair of backslashes is eaten up as an escape, you need *four* in the original string to get things to work, like this

```
my $pattern='\\\\[n"]'
```

which correctly produces the six-character string `\\[n"]`. Now your match `/$pattern/` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, you've explained this very well.

Answer (score 2):

Because the backslash gets interpreted by the regex as escaping the bracket to the character class.

It's equivalent to the line:

```
if ($text =~ /\[n"]/) {
```

The easiest solution is to use a [`qr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) to define your pattern instead:

```
my $text = "\\n";

my $pattern = qr{\\[n"]};

if ($text =~ /$pattern/) {
    print "bingo";
}
```

Outputs:

```
bingo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = qr!\\[n"]!;

while( my $line = <DATA>) {   
    if( $line =~ $pattern ) {
        print $line;
    }
}

__DATA__
1: yes\n
2: no \=
3: yes\"
```

prints:

```
1: yes\n
3: yes\"
```

Comment: It would be nice to see an explanation of why this is different from the OP's code.